# Consume Kafka message with a custom header

Tags: java, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I'm trying to create a kafka Consumer with Spring Cloud Stream in order to listen a Kafka message, built outside any Spring context, with a custom header (**operationType**).

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.x / Spring Cloud Egdware.SR5 and the 1.1.1 version of kafka-client and kafka_2.11.

My Listener class contains this method

```
@StreamListener(value = "dataset-changed", condition = "headers['operationType']=='UPDATE'")
public void onEvent(@Payload DatasetChangedMessage payload) {
  // my code should be execute only if the header operationType == UPDATE
}
```

The Spring Cloud Stream configuration is

```
spring.cloud.stream:
  bindings:
    dataset-changed:
      group: preparation
      content-type: application/json
      destination: dataset-changed
      consumer:
        headerMode: raw
        configuration:
          key.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
          value.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

The producer is a simple java doc with a kafka-client:1.1.1 library

```
Properties producerConfig = new Properties();
producerConfig.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
producerConfig.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
producerConfig.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

KafkaProducer<byte[], String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(producerConfig);

// Headers (to condition the kafka listener)
final List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<>();
headers.add(new RecordHeader("operationType", "UPDATE".getBytes()));

ProducerRecord<byte[], String> record =
        new ProducerRecord<>("dataset-changed", 0, "111".getBytes(), getJsonPayload(), headers);
Future<RecordMetadata> future = producer.send(record);
future.get();

producer.close();
```

When i produce the kafka message, i have this kind of warnings

```
2019-03-15 14:48:32.103  WARN [tdp-preparation,1e24b9764ef9bb14,1e24b9764ef9bb14,false] 34760 --- [           -L-1] .DispatchingStreamListenerMessageHandler : Cannot find a @StreamListener matching for message with id: ea27a446-69da-7b8d-1b94-50b46a40dfde
```

whereas the operationType header is present

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are losing `headers` on the consumer side because you use `headerMode: raw`. That means, essentially, `none` - map no headers.

Consider to use a  `headerMode: headers` instead.

See documentation for more info: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/spring-cloud-stream.html#_consumer_properties

> headerMode
>
> When set to `none`, disables header parsing on input. Effective only for messaging middleware that does not support message headers natively and requires header embedding. This option is useful when consuming data from non-Spring Cloud Stream applications when native headers are not supported. When set to `headers`, it uses the middleware’s native header mechanism. When set to `embeddedHeaders`, it embeds headers into the message payload.
>
> Default: depends on the binder implementation.

Comment: Needs `embeddedHeaders` for 1.3.x.

Comment: You're talking about Spring boot 2. I'm using Spring boot 1.5 and spring cloud Edgware.SR5 and the only available values are embeddedHeaders (default) or raw

Comment: @GaryRussell what do you mean ? the use case isn't supported for spring cloud stream 1.3.X ?

Comment: M-m-m. The problem that you use an Apache Kafka version where there is already a native headers support and you show that with your producer code. You need somehow to be able to extract those headers on the consumer side.

Comment: To access "foreign" headers with 1.3.x. you need to use the kafka11 binder artifact.

Comment: See [the wiki](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/wiki/Kafka-Client-Compatibility). `>To use the 0.11.x.x kafka-clients with 1.3.x, you can use the spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka11 jar (instead of spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka) to get support for native headers. You must also override certain other jar versions.`

Comment: @GaryRussell i'm using the 1.1.1 version of kafka-client and kafka_2.11.

Comment: I can't guarantee it will work with kafka11 binder, YMMV. I believe the 0.11.x.x. client will talk ok to a 1.1.1 broker. See the [Compatibility Matrix](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compatibility+Matrix). But, can't you upgrade to Boot 2.0 or 2.1 to get newer versions of all these libraries?